# Selected tab text disappear in android

Tags: android-fragments

I am trying to make a tab activity, but the selected tab text disappears when I select the tab.
And 2nd thing why there is no underline which shows the selected tab.
Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add these 3 attributes in "com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout"

`app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/white" app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/white" app:tabTextColor="@color/off_white"`